# How can I rotate an ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I am drawing rotated ellipse and hyperbola side-by-side for an illustration of effect of cross product terms in a quadratic. I am learning plotting in tikz through pgfmanual.pgf. I do not find it easy to get the stuff I want, so learning is slow.
I did get some code through the various posts on this forum. I have a few issues to still settle on the plots, to which I would be very grateful for assistance. These are:
1. on the ellipse am not able to put axis labels (I can rotate it ok);
2. I am not able to rotate the hyperbola at all.
The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, decorations.pathreplacing, matrix}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[remember picture,rotate=45]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (2.5,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,1.6);
% draw ellipse
    \draw[line width = 0.5mm] (O) ellipse (2.5cm and 1.60cm);
% draw axis
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (-2.5, 0) -- (2.5, 0) coordinate[right] (e1);
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (0, -2.5) -- (0, 2.5) coordinate[above] (e2);
% calculate brace points for major axis
\path (O) -- (A) coordinate[pos=.02] (a1) coordinate[pos=.98] (a2);
\draw[decorate, decoration = {brace, amplitude = 12pt, mirror, raise =4pt}, yshift = 0pt]
    (a2) -- (a1) coordinate[midway] (tl1);
\coordinate (l1) at ([yshift=1cm]tl1);
% calculate brace points for minor axis
\path (O) -- (B) coordinate[pos=.05] (b1) coordinate[pos=.95] (b2);
\draw[decorate, decoration = {brace, amplitude = 12pt, mirror, raise =4pt}, yshift = 0pt]
    (b2) -- (b1) coordinate[midway] (tl2);
\coordinate (l2) at ([xshift=-.9cm]tl2);
\end{scope}

\draw[line width = 0.5mm, dashed, ->] (-2.5, 0) -- (2.5, 0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, dashed, ->] (0, -2.5) -- (0, 2.5) node[above]{$y$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (e1) {$x^{'}$};
\node[anchor=south east] at (e2) {$y^{'}$};
\node[anchor=south west] at ([xshift=-0.1cm,yshift=-0.4cm]l1) {$a$};
\node[anchor=south east] at ([xshift=.2cm]l2) {$b$};
\end{tikzpicture}
%******

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=-2.5,xmax=2.5,
    ymin=-2.5,ymax=2.5]
    all axes={ticks=few}
    \addplot [black,ultra thick,domain=-1:1] ({cosh(x)}, {sinh(x)});
    \addplot [black,ultra thick,domain=-1:1] ({-cosh(x)}, {sinh(x)});
    \addplot[red,dashed] expression {x};
    \addplot[red,dashed] expression {-x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{document}
```

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: IMHO you're not reading the appropriate doc. You are drawing the second figure with pgplots but not the first one. Why?

Comment: The codes for ellipse and hyperbola were taken from different posts on this forum. I have difficulty understanding either pgfmanual.pdf or pgfplots.pdf, so hard to make what to do given a specific task to accomplish.

Comment: I have got around this by drawing my graphics in geogebra and generate tikz code, I am able to have the graphic I want as well as learn the code